# Delayed change text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with the script jquery:

I have a paragraph of an e-mail. When I click on it. I want the text changed to "Copied to clipboard" with fade effect. After 3 seconds returned the original text with fade efect

I have a problem back to the original text [`(link)`](http://jsfiddle.net/Kwiatkowski/8xd0tgL8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in click event

```
    $('.icon-email').click(function () {
    var email =$(this).text(); 
    $(this).fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).text('Copied to clipboard').fadeIn(500,function()
            {
               $(this).fadeOut(3000, function() {
                          $(this).text(email).fadeIn(500);    
                                               });
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, just something I wanted

Answer (score 0):

you can use the animate function for the above requirement:

```
  $('.icon-email').click(function () {
        $(this).animate({opacity:0},function(){
        $(this).text("new text")
            .animate({opacity:1},3000);  //3000 is the speed that you wanted to fade in and fade out
    })
    });
```